# Does weight come off where it went on?

Tags: weight-loss, weight-gain

Although we know we can't target where weight comes off, if someone gained 20 pounds of fat and then lost 20 pounds of fat with no muscle gain or loss, would they look the same as before? Could it go on the stomach but be lost from the butt?

Comment: As you said, is determined by your genetics where your body stores fat first, and also where it loses fat first. The question should rather be: "Are these two areas the same?"

Comment: I would wish for an answer citing from credible sources, I don't think that hearsay and speculation lead to anything.

Answer (score 3):

In my training I tend to have periods when I deload and just enjoy all kinds of food. That would typically happen during holidays when I give my body full rest for couple weeks. At these moments I gain enough fat to lose any track of my six pack(which happens to an extend because of muscle atrophy as well) and then after I get back on track I am quickly getting rid of all fat once again.

I have noticed and pointed out on many occasions that I tend to gain fat in a certain manner and lose it the same way. For example - I firstly put fat on the sides of my stomach, then on my abs, then on my arms. When I lose fat it starts from my arms, then my abs and lastly lose the fat from the sides and lower back.

I hope my answer helps you. :)

Comment: Well answered young chap, +!

Comment: This is exactly that kind of answer which does not lead to anything (see Informaficker's comment on the OP).

Comment: Actually that's not correct zero.  It goes to show that in some people, such as Arthlete, people lose fat in the same places that they gain it.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't mean that is case in everyone, or even the majority necessarily, but it shows that in some people it is indeed the case, and unless Arthlete is an rare human being, then we can assume that it is most likely that this phenomenon is not a rare one.

Comment: If you are smart enough to interpret anecdotes, then you will find that with proper interpretation they can be quite useful.  In the absence of scientific studies, we first begin with anecdotes first.  Many things in society would never have been proven, if it weren't for humans initially speaking out about their personal experiences of phenomenon.

Comment: @Kenshin - Agreed. Although I can't find it, I remember from my kinesiology classes many moons ago the statement that fat works on the LIFO concept, and that your body has a certain progression for where it stores/retrieves fat.